# How to tell my Eclipse Helios CTD that a project is a C/C++ one?

Tags: c++, c, eclipse, eclipse-cdt

Apparently, my Eclipse CDT doesn't know that my C/C++ project is a C/C++ project.

I created a C/C++ project in my Eclipse Helios from existing sources using the CDT wizard. Selecting the "Properties" entry of the context menu of the project (from the Project View) results in a pop-up window that has a "Builders" entry but no "C/C++ Build" entry; consequently, I'm unable to build the project. It's as if the CDT doesn't know that the project is a C/C++ one even though that's what I told the wizard. The "Resources" entry of the aforementioned pop-up window says that the type of the resource is "Project".

How can I tell the CDT that the project is a C/C++ one?

Answer (score 1):

I've discovered the cause of my problem: selecting the wrong CDT "New Project" wizard. I selected the "Makefile Project with Existing Code" wizard because the makefile and source already existed. I should have selected the "C Project" wizard and told it that the project was an empty makefile project (subtle difference).

Apparently, the "Makefile Project with Existing Code" wizard is a generic one -- even if invoked from within the CDT perspective.